# Android how to process photo

Tags: android, photo

I am working on an android camera-based app with use of Intent. After capturing a photo I can see that photo and two buttons appear - "Save" and "Cancel". What I want to do is to not wait for user to choose one of these two buttons, but start processing this photo and then depending on the result of processing do futher actions.

I've been doing it this way so far :

```
CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

protected void startCameraActivity()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );

    // the method below is my method for setting proper path for my image file
    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name

    startActivityForResult( intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE );
}
```

this method is invoked when I launch my app. So I start my app with camera.
Then I take a photo. And I can choose "Save" or "Cancel". When I choose one this method is invoked :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent

            onPhotoTaken();    // processing...

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
        }
    }
}
```

After receiving proper resultCode I load that image from file and then start processing it.

And now my quesiton is : **If I can get that image before onActivityResult method is invoked? It is invoked after clicking on one of these buttons.**

( I want to do it the similar way google googles does it - user captures a photo and that photo is being processed right away )

Comment: try to use broadcoast receiver.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to implement your own picture taking activity, something along the lines of [this](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/43414.aspx) (which includes source code at the end of the page).

It takes some time to set it up straight, compared to using simple `Intent`, but after that you have direct access to all camera features, including camera image even before it's made available to the calling activity.